# Keycloak Rest API Authentication

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I am trying to customize Keycloak authentication process and expose it as a Rest API.

Keycloak provides a straightforward customization for login and registration html pages (Views),

but what I am trying to achieve is to customize the login or registration process on multiple steps and API's calls, for example my login process will be seperated on three different API's as follow,

one API to validate username and DoB, another API to validate Security question, the last API is to validate the password and generate the token.

What I have done so far is creating custom rest endpoint and custom tables to handle my requirements,
but I feel like  have lost Keycloak abstractions and capabilities,

any advice on how to approach such a requirements utilizing Keycloak.

Thanks in advance

but what I am trying to achieve is to customize the login or registration process on multiple steps and API's calls, for example my login process will be seperated on three different API's as follow,

one API to validate username and DoB, another API to validate Security question, the last API is to validate the password and generate the token.